# Why did I receive an auto-reply from a Gmail account to an email sent a year ago

Tags: gmail

More than a year ago, a Gmail account **A** sent a confidential e-mail to another Gmail account **B**.
Just today, for reasons that we do not understand, **A** received an automatic "on-vacation" reply from **B** to this very old e-mail.

There is no doubt that the automatic reply was actually sent today. How could that happen? Is it a known bug from Gmail?

The motivation for this question is the following: **B** is strongly suspected of illegally disclosing confidential documents to third-parties with malicious intent. Therefore, we fear that **B** may have forwarded the old email from **A** to a third party in a way that somehow resulted in an automatic reply being sent to **A** today. Is it possible? If so, is there any way to find out?